# Ruby gem version numbering

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently started my first gem, but as I was familiarizing myself with the `gem` command, how the build process worked, etc., I published several versions of my gem with varying version numbers before I realized I could simply run `rake install`.

I know the site doesn't give any information regarding deleting/resetting a gem, but is there any way to reset a gem that I started? When I go to "previous versions", every dummy version I published is listed regardless if I yanked it or not. Is there a way to reset this?

Comment: It sounds like if you yank every version that you've published, that will effectively reset it - see http://help.rubygems.org/kb/gemcutter/removing-a-published-rubygem

Comment: So it looks like that works, but it will still (I imagine forever) keep the previous versions so the namespace can never have those versions again. I guess there's no way around this.

Comment: You might want to open an issue with Rubygems to get clarification on this: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help troubleshooting this!

Comment: Published versions are eternal by design. Unpublishing them requires manual intervention by the rubygems.org maintainers, and for good reason.